# It puts wrong null value from String array in HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, null, hashmap

i am a newbie in Java (coming from JavaScript developing on Adobe LiveCycle) and facing the following problem:

I have a String array with several items. I want to put only the items with the value "a" to a HashMap. But instead of 3 "a" values in the HashMap i get 1 null value there. Why is that?

```
    String[] s = {"a", "a", "b", "a"};

    Map m = new HashMap();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i].equals("a")) {
            m.put(i, s[i]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(m.get(i));
    }

    // Prints
    //a
    //a
    //null
```

Comment: You have a `Map<Integer, String>` where key is the index of the string in the array. You shouldn't iterate from 0 to map size, but over map's actual entries. Use `for (Integer key : map.keySet())`

Comment: You put the items with their corresponding index in the `Map`, i.e. you have a `Map` with content `{0=a, 1=a, 3=a}`. Therefore, if you try to access the map with `2` in the `m.get(...)`, you get a `null` since key `2` is not found in the map. On a sidenote: you are using raw types. You should bind the types of the `Map` and `HashMap` properly: `Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();`

Comment: `m.get(i)` Returns the value for key`i`. there you have no index like an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the items with their corresponding index in array `s` in the `Map`, i.e. you have a `Map` with content `{0=a, 1=a, 3=a}`. Therefore if you try to access the map with key `2` (`m.get(2)`), you get a `null` since key `2` is not found in `m`.

Instead of using a `for`-loop over `m`'s size, I recommend iteration over `m`'s [`keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) via a [`foreach`-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

```
for (Object key : m.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("key: " + key + ", value: " + m.get(key));
}
```

On a sidenote: you are using [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). You should bind the types of the `Map` and `HashMap` properly (see the [Javadoc of `Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for details): `Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();`. With properly bound types, `key` in the `for`-loop can be of type `int` or `Integer`. I recommend type `Integer` to avoid unnecessary [Auto(un)boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are putting the items in the map with key `0`, `1` and `3`.

You are taking them out with key `0`, `1`, an `2`.

Use:

```
    for (Object o : m.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(m.get(o));
    }
```

or - better:

```
    Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<>();

    ...

    for (Integer i : m.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(i + " -> " + m.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working correctly, but you are accessing it not correctly.

```
String[] s = {"a", "a", "b", "a"};
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i].equals("a")) {
        m.put(i, s[i]);
    }
}
```

This puts it like this

```
First iteration : m.put(0, "a");
Second iteration : m.put(1, "a");
Third iteration : "b" doest not equal "a" but still counts the index i up
Fourth iteration: m.put(3, "a");
```

Apart from the other answers you can still use your range based loop and access it with an `Iterator`

```
Iterator<String> it = m.values().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
```